# Perl error Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)

Tags: perl

Greeting I try to read a file into hash of hash following this tutorial.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_04.htm

My text input file is

```
event_a1_x1: email1=xxx@gmail.com email2=yyy@gmail.com email1_cnt=3 
event_a1_x2: email1=xxx@gmail.com email2=yyy@gmail.com email1_cnt=3 
event_b2_y1: email1=xxx@gmail.com email2=yyy@gmail.com email1_cnt=3 
event_b2_y2: email1=xxx@gmail.com email2=yyy@gmail.com email1_cnt=3 
event_c3_z1: email1=xxx@gmail.com email2=yyy@gmail.com email1_cnt=3 
event_c3_z2: email1=xxx@gmail.com email2=yyy@gmail.com email1_cnt=3
```

My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get config file on the command line\n";

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

my %HoH;
#open FILE, "filename.txt" or die $!;
my $key;
my $value;
my $who;
my $rec;
my $field;

while ( my $line = <$data>) {
    print $line;
    next unless (s/^(.*?):\s*//);
    $who = $1;
    #print $who;
    $rec = {};
    $HoH{$who} = $rec;
    for $field ( split ) {
        ($key, $value) = split /=/, $field;
        $rec->{$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error...

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./read_config.pl line 18, <$data> line 1.
```

Comment: You assigned to `$line` so you can't use `$_` anymore. So do  `next unless $line =~ s/...//`, and `split` on `$line` below.  OR, remove `my $line` (and all other `$line`s, so just `print;`). Keep working through the good book, this code can be improved a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is about when `$_`, "*the default input and pattern-searching space*", is set and used.

In `while (<$fh>)`, what is read from the filehandle is assigned to `$_`. Then your regex `s///` and [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) and [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) can use it.  See [General Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).

However, once we specifically assign to a variable, `while (my $line = <$fh>)`, this deal is off and `$_` is not set. So when you later use the regex substitution in a way that relies on `$_` the variable is found `uninitialized`.

Either consistently use the default `$_`, or (consistently) don't.  So, either

```
while (<$fh>) { 
    print;
    # same as posted
}
```

or

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # ...
    next unless $line =~ s/^(.*?):\s*//;
    # ...
    foreach my $field (split ' ', $line) {
        # ...
    }
}
```

There is quite a bit more that can be improved in the code, but that would take us elsewhere.